# Access component data in Created or Mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm writing a component for Vue.js and I need to modify data on event. But for some reason, when I access it, it's set as undefined

```
module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.eventHub.$on('minimize', function(window_id) {
            console.log(this.visible);
            this.visible = !this.visible;
        });
    },
    props: ["windowId"]
}
```

When the event is called for the first time, data.visible is undefined, for some reason.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `function (window_id)` has it's own scope, you can not access `this`.

This can be solved by adding `self = this`.

```
 let self = this
 this.eventHub.$on('minimize', function(window_id) {
    console.log(self.visible);
    self.visible = !self.visible;
 });
```

As Nick Rucci pointed out, you can also use an arrow function, and get rid of self = this.

```
this.eventHub.$on('minimize', (window_id) => {
    console.log(this.visible);
    this.visible = !this.visible;
});
```

Comment: Holy macaroni, I'm dumb. Totally forgot about this :D

Thanks!

Comment: @piscator an arrow function would fix this and would be a lot cleaner than defining `let self = this`